# jQuery Toggle functions not executing

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have created a fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/brombomb/kYsN7/

Since slideToggle doesn't work with Table's (due to display: block/table-row issues) I have tried to roll my own with some code I've found on the internet.  As you can see I've included some console.log() for debugging purposes but they never get fired.  I originally had these as separate defined functions but that wasn't working so I rolled them up into the toggle function calls.

Original slide table code: http://www.tino.nl/index.php/2009/08/05/table-animations-in-jquery/

Comment: what you want? slideUP what? slideUP when you click what?

Comment: @jotapdiez The idea would be on thead click slide the tbody up and hide it.  On a second thead click show the tbody and slide it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code does work, I think you may just be misunderstanding what you've done.  The toggle function attaches a click handler to the item it is called on, when clicked it alternates the 2 methods called.  So when you click on your heading this handler is attached **to the body**.  Then clicking on the tbody will cause the slide up (try it, this works).

I think really you intended to attach the handler to the head.  I'm assuming you intend the click on the head to do the hide.  Something more like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/kYsN7/13/

the show isn't working right but I think the structure is more along the lines of what you intended.

Comment: nailed it.  I was attaching the toggle on tbody.  I wanted the toggle attached to the thead but affect the tbody. Got it all up and running.

Comment: Here is a complete and working version for any future issues: http://jsfiddle.net/brombomb/kYsN7/17/  In @kingjiv version he changed the slide up call back to hide the wrong element.  Now it correctly hides the tr instead of the entire body element.

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
   $('#horseStable table thead').click(function() {
      $('#horseStableBody').slideToggle();
   });
```

And that's it. I tested it in your jsfiddle and it works OK. 
Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: I don't see it working in my fiddle at all (even with your code).  The jQuery animation suite is built to toggle block level elements.  The table uses a table-row instead of block, hence it not working. at least not in FF 3.6 or FF 4

Answer (score 0):

Is you really wanting `slide` effect to your `td` elements?

Without animation, you can simple [do it](http://jsfiddle.net/ErickPetru/WgRGD/2/):

```
$('#horseStable table thead').click(function() {
    if ($("#horseStableBody td").is(":visible")) {
        $("#horseStableBody td").hide();
    } else {
        $("#horseStableBody td").show();
    }

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Yes, I really want the slide element.  I have a bunch of other features elsewhere on my site that all implement a slide toggle.  To be consistent I would like to slide toggle.